# Пытаюсь сделать всплывающее меню в HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Вот это меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при наведении курсора должно отобразиться так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мой вопрос таков
Как зафиксировать иконки на своих местах чтобы при наведении меню раскрывалось а они стояли на месте?

Мой код

```
    <div class="page">
<div class="menu">
    <ol>
        <li><img src="image/pencil.png" alt=""><span>Test</span></li>
        <li><img src="image/heart.png" alt=""><span>Test</span></li>
        <li><img src="image/clock.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image/shield.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image/equalizer.png" alt=""></li>
    </ol>
</div>   
<div class="text">
<pre>
      много текста
</pre>
```

Пока результат такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался написать position: fixed; но иконки вставали друг на друга

просто пожалуйста дайте совет как зафиксировать иконки на местах чтобы при наведении мышки они стояли а текст выплывал слева на право

Надеюсь я смог объяснить что мне нужно

по просьбе в комментах добавил CSS код

```css
.page {
    display: inline-flex;
}

ol {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

li {
    margin: 100px 0;
    display: flex;
}

span {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
}

.text {
    margin-left: 130px;
}

.menu:hover {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="page">
    <div class="menu">
        <ol>
            <li><img src="image/pencil.png" alt=""><span>Test</span></li>
            <li><img src="image/heart.png" alt=""><span>Test</span></li>
            <li><img src="image/clock.png" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="image/shield.png" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="image/equalizer.png" alt=""></li>
        </ol>
    </div>   
    <div class="text">
    <pre>
          много текста
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: css код в студию

Comment: Добавил, но там просто пару строк чтобы расставить элементы
И да "много текста" там реально много текста просто он слишком огромный чтобы я туда его копировал поэтому я написал 2 слова

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> как зафиксировать иконки на местах чтобы при наведении мышки они стояли а текст выплывал слева на право

Просто уменьшите размер шрифта надписей до нуля, а при наведении восстанавливайте исходный:

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.page {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: max-content;
  background-color: #8a8a8a;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover { background-color: #696969; }

img { height: 30px; width: 30px; }

span {
  margin-left: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: margin-left .4s ease-out, font-size .4s ease-in-out, opacity .4s ease-in;
}
.menu:not(:hover) span {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out, font-size .4s ease-in-out, opacity .4s ease-out;
}

.text {
  padding-left: 100px;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="menu">
    <p>MENU</p>
    <ol>
      <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gjz7sQ8RpOWGVtMb0OWmPKpdI1wYarHOsiiG3EqrQ=k-s64" alt=""><span>EDIT</span></li>
      <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gjz7sQ8RpOWGVtMb0OWmPKpdI1wYarHOsiiG3EqrQ=k-s64" alt=""><span>FAVORITES</span></li>
      <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gjz7sQ8RpOWGVtMb0OWmPKpdI1wYarHOsiiG3EqrQ=k-s64" alt=""><span>HISTORY</span></li>
      <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gjz7sQ8RpOWGVtMb0OWmPKpdI1wYarHOsiiG3EqrQ=k-s64" alt=""><span>SECURITY</span></li>
      <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gjz7sQ8RpOWGVtMb0OWmPKpdI1wYarHOsiiG3EqrQ=k-s64" alt=""><span>SETTINGS</span></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error inventore similique sequi ab sint quisquam corporis nulla eligendi corrupti, mollitia eaque modi, unde ratione dolor voluptas, nam magnam quos. Culpa.
Ducimus qui iusto voluptatibus ipsam beatae in perferendis quam ratione? Deserunt ducimus ad incidunt aspernatur animi cupiditate debitis a eos neque temporibus nesciunt cum praesentium, aliquam nulla quae nemo voluptatibus?
Temporibus nulla, mollitia ab qui velit amet illo, voluptate sint saepe nemo tempora beatae totam ratione veritatis. Esse blanditiis, minima quod, eaque facere nemo alias odio ex tempora maxime odit.
Nam veniam animi temporibus consequatur nostrum voluptatem error cupiditate, fuga ipsam nulla quisquam sequi fugiat non tempora culpa aperiam facere repellat eum deserunt, rem ex dignissimos. Cupiditate inventore ipsum quisquam.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Боже это отличная идея!! Огромное спасибо
Я сегодня придумал как по другому сделать но ваша идея намного лучше